# Bad translation with Djangojs app Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, translation

i've an issue with my Django APP.

I've tried to translate one string in JS file with javascript_catalogue. My string is only translated in english if i give a value to my string in local/en/LC_MESSAGES/Djangojs.po

Admin user can change WebApp language with Ajax like this:

```
def language(request):
'''
'''
if not request.is_ajax():                       #on verifi qu'on accede à la fonction par une requete ajax
    return HttpResponse('Not an ajax request...')
if not request.method == 'GET':
    return HttpResponse('Not a post ajax request...')#on verifie que le type de requete est valide
language_code = request.GET.get('langue')
settings.LANGUAGE_CODE = language_code


return HttpResponse()
```

And Django sends template like this:

```
template = loader.get_template('my_template')
translation.activate(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
html = template.render()
return HttpResponse(html)
```

in urls.py:

```
js_info_dict = {
        'domain': 'djangojs',
        'packages': ('IHMWEB',),
  }

urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^jsi18n/$', javascript_catalog, js_info_dict, name='javascript-catalog'),
        url(r'^$',                  IHMWEB.views.login),
                        ..
                        ..
```

MyAPP.settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'IHMWEB'
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr'

gettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', gettext('English')),
    ('fr', gettext('French')),
    ('de', gettext('German')),
    ('it', gettext('Italian')),
    ('qa', gettext('Arabic')),

)
```

In my template i create a menu with title:

```
        textnode = document.createElement('i');
        textnode.setAttribute("class", "fa fa-plus");
        title = gettext("Ajouter un module"); //"Ajouter un module" is french translation for "Add module" 
        textnode.setAttribute("title", title);
```

And finally Djangojs.po:
en/LC_MESSAGES/djangojs.po

```
#: frontend/src/MODS/index/js/index.js:70
msgid "Ajouter un module"
msgstr "Add new bundle"
```

fr/LC_MESSAGES/djangojs.po

```
#: frontend/src/MODS/index/js/index.js:70
msgid "Ajouter un module"
msgstr "Ajouter un module"
```

If Admin chooses french language, my whole html is translated in french but the string in my js is translated in english.

If Admin chooses english language, my whole html is translated in english and the string in my js is translated in english.

**UPDATE**: i forget to mention something
template.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'javascript-catalog' %}"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach you can take is writing out all your templates and placing the strings within `trans` and `blocktrans` tags with `i18n` at the top.

this will update your django.po with your strings and handle translations.

You can also use `get_language()` to get the users current language.

Comment: get_language() give me current LANGUAGE_CODE in Django. I can see that when admin change current language, LANGUAGE_CODE change too. My problem is only djangojs.po in english is load, even if user language is 'fr' and LANGUAGE_CODE is fr...

Comment: I would suggest a simpler approach where you set the string on the view -  pass to template -let template translate from po - use js to grab them and apply as needed.

`var title = '{% trans title_you_passed_in %}`

Comment: it will also be easier to continue with more languages.  you only have to add po translations and make messages for your text to translate from then on